# My R code is taking too long and is too complex

Tags: r, dplyr

Using big data sets, this code is taking a really long time to process. Does anyone have any simpler ways of running it?

Ran this code, locked up my machine for a while

```
SID_Scores <- filtered %>%
  group_by(SalesPerson_SID) %>%
  summarise(
    Brand_Advocacy = mean(Q1, na.rm = TRUE),
    Vehicle_Satisfaction = mean(Q2, na.rm = TRUE),
    Dealer_Satisfaction = mean(Q3, na.rm = TRUE),
    Sales_Advocacy = mean(Q6N_srvsls_Recommend_10Pt, na.rm = TRUE),
    Overall_SalesCon = mean(Q5N1_ovrsls, na.rm = TRUE),
    Understanding_Needs = mean(Q7N1_slsneeds, na.rm = TRUE),
    Product_Features = mean(Q7N2_slsfeat, na.rm = TRUE),
    Professional_Court = mean(Q7N3_slsprof, na.rm = TRUE),
    Feel_Valued = mean(SlsValued, na.rm = TRUE),
    Trustworthy = mean(SlsTrustworthy, na.rm = TRUE),
    Financial_Arrang = mean(Q5N2_ovrfin, na.rm = TRUE),
    Financial_Agreement = mean(Q8N2_finease, na.rm = TRUE),
    Respect_Time = mean(Q8N3_fintime, na.rm = TRUE),
    Honesty = mean(Q8N4_finhon, na.rm = TRUE),
    Delivery = mean(Q5N3_ovrdlv, na.rm = TRUE),
    U_Pairing = (sum(filtered$Q_UCPairing == '1', na.rm = TRUE)) / (
      sum(filtered$Q_UCPairing == '1', na.rm = TRUE) +
        sum(filtered$Q_UCPairing == '2', na.rm = TRUE)
    ),
    U_Demonstrate = (sum(filtered$Q_UCDemonstrate == '1', na.rm = TRUE)) /
      (
        sum(filtered$Q_UCDemonstrate == '1', na.rm = TRUE) +
          sum(filtered$Q_UCDemonstrate == '2', na.rm = TRUE)
      ),
    U_FreeTrials =  (sum(filtered$Q_UCFreeTrials == '1', na.rm = TRUE)) /
      (
        sum(filtered$Q_UCFreeTrials == '1', na.rm = TRUE) +
          sum(filtered$Q_UCFreeTrials == '2', na.rm = TRUE)
      ),
    U_Presets = (sum(filtered$Q_UCRadioPreset == '1', na.rm = TRUE)) /
      (
        sum(filtered$Q_UCRadioPreset == '1', na.rm = TRUE) +
          sum(filtered$Q_UCRadioPreset == '2', na.rm = TRUE)
      )
  ) %>%
  group_by(SalesPerson_SID)
```

This has been running for several hours now. Filtered has 540000 rows with 35 variables

Here is the code to reproduce some sample data:

```
structure(list(EventType = c("001", "001", "001", "001", "001", 
"001"), `Survey Type` = c("Sales", "Sales", "Sales", "Sales", 
"Sales", "Sales"), ModelYear = c(2018, 2019, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018), PurchaseDate = c(20181209, 20181216, 20181209, 20181215, 
20181218, 20181218), `ZoneCode (BC)` = c("32", "71", "71", "51", 
"63", "74"), SalesDistrict = c("G", "D", "G", "C", "T", "G"), 
    SalesGroupSize = c("E", "E", "B", "D", "D", "B"), DealerCode = c("60698", 
    "45622", "69319", "36277", "44107", "26922"), Q1 = c(9, 8, 
    10, 10, 10, 9), Q2 = c(9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9), Q3 = c(8, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 9), Q6N_srvsls_Recommend_10Pt = c(9, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 9), Q5N1_ovrsls = c(8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8), Q5N2_ovrfin = c(9, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 7), Q5N3_ovrdlv = c(8, NA, 10, 10, 10, 6), 
    Q5N4_srvsls_facility = c(9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10), Q7N1_slsneeds = c(9, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 9), Q7N2_slsfeat = c(9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9
    ), Q7N3_slsprof = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9), Q8N1_finneg = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), Q8N2_finease = c(9, 
    10, 10, 9, 10, 7), Q8N3_fintime = c(9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10
    ), Q8N4_finhon = c(9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9), Q9 = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), SlsValued = c(9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8), SlsTrustworthy = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), SlsPaperwork = c(NA, 
    3, 2, 2, 2, NA), `SlsF&ITransaction` = c(3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4
    ), SalesPerson_SID = c("S39547M", "S56830O", "S35478Q", "S61788P", 
    "S35680B", "S75254K"), Q_UCPairing = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    Q_UCDemonstrate = c(1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1), Q_UCFreeTrials = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Q_UCRadioPreset = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .Names = c("EventType", 
"Survey Type", "ModelYear", "PurchaseDate", "ZoneCode (BC)", 
"SalesDistrict", "SalesGroupSize", "DealerCode", "Q1", "Q2", 
"Q3", "Q6N_srvsls_Recommend_10Pt", "Q5N1_ovrsls", "Q5N2_ovrfin", 
"Q5N3_ovrdlv", "Q5N4_srvsls_facility", "Q7N1_slsneeds", "Q7N2_slsfeat", 
"Q7N3_slsprof", "Q8N1_finneg", "Q8N2_finease", "Q8N3_fintime", 
"Q8N4_finhon", "Q9", "SlsValued", "SlsTrustworthy", "SlsPaperwork", 
"SlsF&ITransaction", "SalesPerson_SID", "Q_UCPairing", "Q_UCDemonstrate", 
"Q_UCFreeTrials", "Q_UCRadioPreset"))
```

Comment: We don't have any of your data, so there's no way to know what's going on or what needs to be improved. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making reproducible R examples. Just guessing, you might reshape your data so you're not repeating the same summary operations, and trade `dplyr` for a faster solution like `data.table`

Comment: Why recalculating the global sums over and over within group?

Comment: @MichaelM, because each group has different counts for each type and I thought I needed to do it this way because of the summarise command

Comment: @camille Is there a way to extract just a few rows from a data frame but have it produce the code to share the values here? Also, I am not familiar with `data.table`

Comment: Click the link in my comment on how to share a sample of your data

Comment: Regarding your answer to my comment: your sum is over filtered$Q_UCFreeTrials, which is non grouped structure. If the sums should be within group, drop the `filtered$`.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelM it ran perfectly. I think I understand.

Comment: Great! Glad it worked.